# Show icon on hover in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have below line of code which show icon with suggestions

```
<span className="notify-close" onClick={() =>this.test(item)} ><img src={"/img/crossgrey.png"}/></span>
```

full code is this

```
private onRenderCell = (item: any) => {
    if (item.key !== -1) {
      return (
        <div key={item.key}
          className={SuggestionListItemStyle.root}
          data-is-focusable={true}
          onKeyDown={(ev: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => this.handleListItemKeyDown(ev, item)}>
          <div id={'link' + item.key}
            style={SuggestionListStyle()}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>
            {item.displayValue}
           
          </div>
          <span className="notify-close" onClick={() =>this.test(item)} ><img src={"/img/crossgrey.png"}/></span>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div key={item.key} data-is-focusable={true}>
          {item.displayValue}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

But its  required that icon should be shown only on hover below is my different ts file where style is written for hover

```
export const SuggestionListItemStyle = mergeStyleSets({
  root: {
    selectors: {
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: DefaultColors.Item.ListItemHoverBackgroundColor
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Can any one help me on this ?